# Objective-C: Save Text. Best solution?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

This may sound like a noobish question (in fact, it is), but I can't figure out what I should use to save between sessions:

- NSStrings
- NStextStorages

I've found some alternatives, but I don't know which is best for the case and why:

- Core Data (or has it nothing to do?)
- SQL

**Edit:** I have a simple interface that adds "posts" to a database (that doesn't exist yet, hence my question). Each "post" has a "title" one or two "authors" and a "body". While the "title" and the "authors" are plain strings (`NSStrings`), the "body" is rich text (`NSTextStorage`). But I don't want to save files, I want to generate a database that I could then use to format automatically and generate a PDF file (for me to print). I've been reading Core Data and it looks like the way to go, I'm just not sure how I could then convert my data and format it into a PDF.

Comment: Please describe, in detail, how you’re using text in your application: what does your app do? What kinds of text (plain strings, rich text, rich text with attachments, etc.) and how much text do you need to preserve, and in what quantity? How will the text be used? (For example, a name of a recipe that you would like to be able to query). Is the text going to be saved into user-created document files? There are hundreds of possible ways to preserve text; to know which ones are appropriate, we need more info on how the text will be used.

Comment: [NSString writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJFFBDJ)

Comment: Also, the PDF part is really a second question - feel free to open as many Q's as you like on SO and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data would probably be great for what you're doing, although anything you do with Core Data you can probably do with SQL if you already know it.

Read [the Core Data guides](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/index.php?Search=Core+Data).  Basically you lay out your schema and then can add or remove managed objects from the managed object context.  Core Data is nice because it can do a lot of validation for free, and is good performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation not too long ago.. and although im developing for iPhone, i belive the principle would be the same.. i found core data to be very useful, once i got to grips with it it proved to be quite useful..

if your saving a lot of information/data, than core data may be the way to go..

hope this helps :)